# What is the best idea for making a system for showing demo of templates that are html css and javascript

Tags: php

I want make a system for showing demo of my themes.
All themes files are in a folder and they are `HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript` files with relative paths .
the system folders are like below :

```
-index.php  
-themes  
--theme1
--theme2
```

I want send a request to index file then index file loads the requested file.
First thing that i want is preventing direct access to themes folder (i want prevent the access to this folder so only `PHP` able to access it).
But if i do it , then i need to load HTML files with Ajax by getting the contents with `PHP`, and problem with Ajax and `PHP` is that I'm not able to load its external `css` and js files , also i don't know how to load another pages that are linked from index file of a theme .
After above approach i decided to use HTML `iframe` tag , but this tag needs direct URL to a file and this way hiding themes folder is not possible.
Now i want know is there any better way for doing this ? or is there any thing that I think about it in a incorrect way ?
Please keep in mind i don't want users be able to direct access to themes because maybe they load my themes in their site without showing my **demo bar** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts come to mind:

Instead of going to all the trouble because of the demo bar; you could disallow hotlinking with e.g. htaccess -- and if people copy your theme; i guess a demo bar can be removed easily so no reason there.

But if you really want it, here's an idea:

1. Create a php array with the names of the themes, which are going to get called through the url for example, assign them the foldername of the theme, so e.g:

   ```
    $themes['fancytheme'] = 'f4ncyth3me';
   ```
2. Store the theme and or directory in a session
3. Make sure that js/ and css/ links are being passed through the index.php, either by linking them in your themes, or by creating a rewrite rule in htaccess
4. If you get a js or css request in your index, check the session which directory should be prefixed and return the raw output of the file.

   Alternatively to the session, you could also include the theme name in the js/ css/ urls so you also know what to include in the index.

Comment: Nice approach but step 3 is very hard. because there is a lot of files within every theme folder and editing all that files is not possible. can you please give me an example of .htaccess code ?

Comment: Thank you, disallow hotlinking resolved the problem !

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you are going to render a webpage to a browser, no matter how much effort you put into it, someone will at some level be able to download and use any requested javascript, html, and CSS.

You can include in your theme folders a check for what the HTTP Referrer is (ie, `if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "mydomain.com/demos") { die("Beat it punk!") }` but referrers are sent from a browser and an unscrupulous person could spoof them.  The other approach would be to store valid session ID's in your demo toolbar area.  What you are essentially creating is somewhat of a login check..

While I believe this would achieve what you are looking for (Preventing company X from masquerading as you, the hardworking designer to prospective clients (as most clients likely will not be masking their HTTP referrer by default) by simply hotlinking to your themes, **it doesn't address the underlying issue of "I want to keep my code private"**.

If it is rendered to a browser, someone can steal it, and I am guessing that to avoid detection that they would prefer to simply wget everything and host it on their site rather then tip you off by leaving referrals from them hotlinking to your content in your server logs.

I would suggest if you want to keep the code private, maybe just make the themes a large image for demonstration purposes..

Comment: If i set a session then how i can check if session is set or not ? lets think i set a session in demo bar file , and a user types a direct link to that theme file , so how checking that session is possible ?

Comment: on your root index.php file, you would say include `session_start(); $_SESSION['came_from_index'] = TRUE;` or similar, and in your individual template folders, you would need `session_start(); if(!$_SESSION['came_from_index']) { die("Beat it punk!") }`  The webserver will let someone go from the index and load the theme file, but only for that session (meaning they had to have come from a place where that session variable is set)  If the session is destroyed or times out, then your variable would never be set, allowing you to kick people out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to protect your HTML,JS,CSS code then do not bother trying to protect your code. Bcoz if somebody can see it on a browser , then it can be duplicated.

What you can do is make it less readable . ie encrypt these files. There are many tools online
which help you to encrypt html,js,css code. These will only make it harder for somebody to steal your code,  not impossible.

Otherwise whatever you are going to do is only going to hurt genuine users who do not want to hack your code. Professionals will get your html,js,css code whatever you do.

check this link http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/article.php/3875651/Web-Developer-Class-How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code.htm

Comment: I don't want to hide any src just i don't want let others uses my host for loading demo of that theme :D

Comment: If that is all you are trying to achieve then I believe you can have server setting that allows only linking to files from localhost . Such option exist in all most server environment.